# Overloading << operator to print vector contents

Tags: c++

I've looked up information for overloading the << operator, and it seems like I did everything correctly, but I keep getting a compile error.  I've friended this function in my header file, and placed a prototype at the top of my cpp file.

My University.h:

```
#ifndef UNIVERSITY_H
#define UNIVERSITY_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "Department.h"
#include "Student.h"
#include "Course.h"
#include "Faculty.h"
#include "Person.h"


class University
{
  friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const vector<Department>& D);
  friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Department& department);

 protected:
  vector<Department> Departments;
  vector<Student> Students;
  vector<Course> Courses;
  vector<Faculty> Faculties;
  static bool failure;
  static bool success;


 public:

  bool CreateNewDepartment(string dName, string dLocation, long dChairID);
  bool ValidFaculty(long dChairID);
};

#endif
```

My University.cpp:

```
#ifndef UNIVERSITY_CPP
#define UNIVERSITY_CPP

#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "University.h"

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<Department>& D);
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Department& department);

bool University::failure = false;
bool University::success = true;


bool University::CreateNewDepartment(string dName, string dLocation, long dChairID)
{
  if((dChairID != 0) && (ValidFaculty(dChairID)== University::failure))
    {
      Department D(dName, dLocation, dChairID);
      Departments.push_back(D);
      for (int i = 0; i < Departments.size(); i++)
         cout << Departments;
      return University::success;
    }
  return University::failure;
}

bool University::ValidFaculty(long dChairID)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Faculties.size(); i++)
    {
      if (Faculties[i].ID == dChairID)
        return University::success;
    }
  return University::failure;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vector<Department>& D)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < D.size(); i++)
     os << D[i] << endl;
  os << "\n";
  return os;
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Department& department)
{
    department.Print(os);
    return os;
}

#endif
```

My Department.h:

```
#ifndef DEPARTMENT_H
#define DEPARTMENT_H

#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Department
{
  friend class University;
  friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, Department& department);

 protected:
  long ID;
  string name;
  string location;
  long chairID;
  static long nextDepartID;

 public:
  Department();
  Department(string dName, string dLocation, long dChairID);
  void Get();
  void Print(ostream& os)const;
};

#endif
```

My Department.cpp:

```
#ifndef DEPARTMENT_CPP
#define DEPARTMENT_CPP

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

#include "Department.h"

long Department::nextDepartID = 100;

Department::Department()
{
  ID = nextDepartID++;
  name = "Null";
  location = "Null";
  chairID = 0;
}

Department::Department(string dName, string dLocation, long dChairID):name(dName), location(dLocation), chairID(dChairID)
{
  ID = nextDepartID++;
}

void Department::Get()
{
}

void Department::Print(ostream& os)const
{
  os << "\n";
  os << ID << endl;
  os << name << endl;
  os << location << endl;
  os << chairID << endl;
  os <<"\n\n";
}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Department& department)
{
  department.Print(os);
  return os;
}
#endif
```

Now everything can be seen that pertains only to this problem.  The only error I receive now is that void value is not being ignored.

Snippet of error:

```
University.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Department&)’:
University.cpp:53: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
Department.cpp: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Department&)’:
Department.cpp:42: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

FINAL EDIT:

Thanks to everyone that helped me.  I definitely have a better understanding of operator overloading now...especially when it deals with printing vectors of user-defined types!

Comment: Looks like you haven't defined `<<` for `const Department&`.

Comment: ... and the *exact* text of the error messages probably shows that.

Comment: A streaming operator for `Department` objects themselves?  The telltale sign is the "os <<" in the message, which indicates it's a problem with the above operator's implementation, rather than anything to do with matching that operator during client usage.

Comment: @paddy - I guess I'm not understanding what you mean by your comment.  Should I also be defining this in my Department class?

Comment: You need two operators... `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Department&)` for printing individual `Department` objects - which you'd normally put in the same file(s) as the `Department` code, and the operator in your question layered on top of that to print `vector<Department>`.

Comment: @KevinSimpsonII Yes, you can define it in the class if you want, as `std::ostream& Department::operator<<( std::ostream& ) const`

Comment: @WhozCraig - the error message says a lot of things I don't entirely understand.  If I were a god with C++ I wouldn't be here.  Please keep that in mind when you decide to comment on other's posts.  I'm sure there was a time when you didn't understand this language too.

Comment: @KevinSimpsonII The reason we're *here* is because we likely *do* understand, *unless you choose not to post the message in the first place*. When you have an ache or pain and go to the doctor, you don't just walk in and tell him/her "It hurts" and offer no specifics that maybe *you* don't understand, *but he does*. We don't expect you to understand every error message, but if you don't, at least bring it here so we can help you understand it.

Comment: @TonyD - I think I'm picking up what you're throwing down.  I have implemented the first part of your comment in my Department.h and Department.cpp files.  The vector I wish to print is located in my University class.  That vector does not exist in my Department class.

Comment: @paddy Um.. that would be an interesting insertion operation. `Department dept; dept << std::cout;`

Comment: @KevinSimpsonII Your code for your vector dump operator looks like it will be a decent template for your `Department` class operator, just without the `std::vector` as the second argument, and rather using `const Department&`. They should look almost the same , in fact, except in the latter you're dumping members of your `Department` object rather than a vector (speaking of which, if you implement that Department stream inserter you could use a copy-ostream-iterator instead. I'll type it up on ideone.com if you want  to see what it looks like. Its actually pretty slick).

Comment: @TonyD - I already have a print function in my Department class.  Any object created has access to that.  I thought I was understanding what you were saying, but clearly I'm not.  I'm sure anyone reading this knows that the vector I'm trying to print is of type Department...which can include different types.  This vector is only located in my University class.  Why would I need to overload the operator for my Department class?

Comment: @WhozCraig - So I definitely need to define two separate operators.  I guess an example of what you're referring to would be great.  I'll check out that site you mentioned.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh dear, looks like I've hit my brain limit for the day.  Thanks for calling me out =)

Comment: @KevinSimpsonII If you have a `Department::print(std::stream& os);` method for `Department`, in your code above you can just call `D[i].print(os);` if that member looks like what I think it does. Is that what your `print` method does for a `Department`? (and good foresight for you if it does, btw). If so, then you don't need to provide an operator overload for `Department` (but doing so is trivial since you already have `print` at your disposal to use in doing so.)

Comment: @WhozCraig - I have a Department::Print()const function.  I'll edit my post so no one is guessing what I'm doing.  Standby.

Comment: @KevinSimpsonII Post is up [on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/E1skyE) if you have the spare time to peruse.

Comment: Hopefully this shines more light on the problem.

Comment: @WhozCraig - I've posted all pertinent files instead of pieces of code here and there.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: The only issue with implementing WhozCraig's suggestion above is that your `Print()` function is `void Department::Print() const` and hardcoding `cout`.  You should change it to `void Department::Print(std::ostream& os) const` and internally to use `os` instead of `cout`.  Still, it's a pain to have to remember which classes have `Print` vs `print` vs `out` etc. which is a good reason to go one step further - adding `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Department& d) { d.Print(os); return os; }` - which lets your original `vector<Department>` printing code work.

Comment: @TonyD - I was able to shrink the mass error message.  I have included ostream& os in my print function.  The only errors I receive now is "void value not being ignored as it ought to be".  I have also changed those cout statements to os.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why there is a problem.  The Print function isn't returning anything at all, so it's still "void".

Comment: I have figured it out.  I made some dumb errors.  In my CreateNewDepartment function where I was printing the contents of my vector, I had to remove [i].  It is printing like a champ.

Comment: @KevinSimpsonII That'll teach me to go watch a football game in the middle of the evening =P. Glad it works for you.

Answer (score 4):

The complaint was that while your function to iterate over and print the vector contents may have been correct, the actual object contained by the vector did not have an `operator<<` specified.

You need to have one.

If you already have a method called `Print()` in your `Department` class, you could simply create an overload for `operator<<` as follows:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Department& department) {
    os<<department.Print();
    return os;
}
```

I had prepared the following code before you posted your update. Maybe it can help you.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

class Department {
 public:
  Department(const std::string& name)
      : m_name(name) { }
  std::string name() const {
    return m_name;
  }
 private:
  std::string m_name;  
};


// If you were to comment this function, you would receive the
// complaint that there is no operator<< defined.
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Department& department) {
  os<<"Department(\""<<department.name()<<"\")";
  return os;
}

// This is a simple implementation of a method that will print the
// contents of a vector of arbitrary type (not only vectors, actually:
// any container that supports the range-based iteration): it requires
// C++11.
template<typename T>
void show(const T& container) {
  for(const auto& item : container) {
    std::cout<<item<<std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  std::vector<Department> deps = {{"Health"}, {"Defense"}, {"Education"}};
  show(deps);
}
```

Compile with `g++ example.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra` (I used OS X 10.7.4 and GCC 4.8.1) to get:

```
$ ./a.out 
Department("Health")
Department("Defense")
Department("Education")
```